# Get MAX ID from multiple records in table where ID2 is the same and where Value 3<>0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image: CLICK FOR IMAGE FILE]

In the above screenshot I need to get the subplanid where MAX(ID) in that group of subplanid does not have a formularymixtype of 0

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by subplanid order by id desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and formularymixtype <> 0;
```

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 't'.

Comment: @tdipl . . . That is where your table name goes.

Comment: sorry I'm new to this. That worked great. Thanks a lot Gord

Comment: i believe he is looking for mssql, not mysql

Answer (score 0):

This query will query out subplainid  from table where will take last id and formularymixtype is not equal to 0

```
 SELECT subplainid FROM table t 
    where id = (select max(id) from table where formularymixtype <> 0 )
```